# Retrieve userId from url with AngularJs

Tags: angularjs, angular-routing

I'm learning AngularJs at present and I've hit a brick wall due to my lack of knowledge on it.

What I'm trying to do is pass in a Id (guid) within the URL and inside my controller I'll retrieve it and pass it to a WebApi to return some data linked to that Id.

However I'm unable to get the route correct, my currently URL looks like this:

http://localhost:15216/

When I pass in the Id it will look something like this

http://localhost:15216/573637

Quite straight forward, my page is called index.html, after browsing the web and looking at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21256947/passing-id-into-url-for-individual-view-in-angular-js) and basically replicating what he/she has provided I'm still unable to retrieve the value from my URL.

This is my current configuration:

```
var myApp = angular.module('christmasvip', ['ngRoute'])
   .config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
   $routeProvider.when('/:userId', { templateUrl: '/index.html', controller: 'mainController' }).
   otherwise({ redirectTo: '/index.html' });
}]);
```

And this is my Controller:

```
myApp.controller("mainController", function ($scope, $http, $routeParams) {

var userId = $routeParams.userId;

alert(userId);

});
```

I then manipulate the URL so it would look like :

http://localhost:15216/573637

But when I alert the userId it say's "underfined"

I've also included angular-route.js in my project

Any help/solution would be great.

Answer (score 0):

In the [documentation of ngRoute](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$routeParams) you can find an example... Try using the URL: http://localhost:15216/index.html#/573637

```
// Given:
// URL: http://server.com/index.html#/Chapter/1/Section/2?search=moby
// Route: /Chapter/:chapterId/Section/:sectionId
//
// Then
$routeParams ==> {chapterId:'1', sectionId:'2', search:'moby'}
```

Comment: thanks for coming back to me, I've gone through the documentation you linked, I've tried the URL example you provided however I''m still unable to grab the Id, I did use console.log($routeProvider); and I can see the object within the developer tools but it's empty

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the url

http://localhost:15216/#/573637

I assume your root is http://localhost:15216/

Comment: tried that, but it doesn't alert the number 573637 instead I get undefined still

Answer (score 0):

your confusing the `$routeProvider` in the config you say

```
.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/:userId', { templateUrl: '/index.html', controller:'mainController' }).
```

so your telling it, "if we see any url like this '/anything' take 'anything' and supply it as a parameter to the `$routeParam` service

then you add

```
otherwise({ redirectTo: '/index.html' });
```

which tells it, if you get any other url redirect to "/index.html", but `index.html` is something so its going to want to route you to '/' with the route param as 'index.html'

also you need to make sure you have `<ng-view></ng-view>` inside of your index.html file for the `$routeProvider` to load the route correctly, that is probably your main issue, but the first thing i mentioned would probably be an error once you add it.